# Is there a way to click through GDPR privacy policies on webpages when web scraping in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the the article text from articles like the following:

http://fortune.com/2017/05/05/chemchina-syngenta-deal-acquisition/

However, some websites, such as Fortune, will present a screen on your first visit on which you must consent to them using your data in certain ways.

I need my webscraping tool to move through this page and access and download the article html.

Answer (score 0):

If you're required to perform actions on the page, you should look into using Selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Selenium is a *webdriver* which is exactly what it sounds like. It allows you to open a headless browser session which you drive via python code. You'll be able to parse through the HTML of the GDPR page, find the specific button/link/whatever you need to continue, send a keypress, then parse the following page to get the article text.

A webdriver is a great tool to use when you need to interact with a webserver via Javascript. Like triggering a server to send you more HTML by scrolling to the bottom of a page (to account for sites that implement lazy loading). This could come in handy for websites that require you to scroll to the bottom of an agreement before the "Agree" button is activated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have two problems that I would now need to overcome which stem from that fact that some pages will have a GDPR page and some will not. First, how to identify that a GDPR page I need to click through has come up. And second, how to click through the GDPR page.

Comment: I would test for something that is consistent across pages that have a GDPR page, like some amount of text. You would use ```driver.page_source``` which will give you the HTML. You would parse that to test if it is a GDPR page. As far as clicking through it, use your browser's dev tools (right click an element and click inspect) to determine what button needs to be clicked. There are plenty of tutorials online that go over this in great detail.(e.g. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html)